# How to fix transparent div child in parent?

Tags: opacity, css

I have the CSS declare bellow:

```
#loadingBox-holder
{
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    position:fixed;
    left:0;
    top:0;
    filter: alpha(opacity=30);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(opacity=30);
    opacity:0.7;
    -moz-opacity: 0.7; 
    z-index: 1000;
    background-color:#000;
}

#loadingBox
{
    position: fixed;
    left: 40%;
    top: 50%;
    z-index: 1000;
    height: 36px;
    width: 138px;
    border:1px solid #ccc;
    background:#fff !important;
    padding:5px 5px 10px 10px;
    opacity:100;

    /*-moz-opacity: 100 !important; */

}
```

and HTML:

```
<div id="loadingBox-holder" style="">
                <div id="loadingBox">
                    <p>Please wait...</p>
                    <img src="../Images/loading.gif" alt="" />
                </div>
            </div>
```

The code above is a loadding indicator. My problem is the loadingBox-hold is gray transparent but I want the loadingBox is normal not transprent. I add the css bellow:

```
filter: alpha(opacity=100);
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(opacity=100);
opacity:1;
-moz-opacity: 1;
```

However the child div still transparent.

Where is my mistakes and how to fix that ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using `position fixed` then moving loadingBox out of holder would not make any difference in the final output and it'll fix your opacity issue.

```
<div id="loadingBox-holder" style="">
</div> 

<div id="loadingBox">
    <p>Please wait...</p>
</div>
​
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/6kAC8/1/)

Comment: Simple and usefull ! Thanks !